# ytdapi.videos.insert: cert already in hash table

Tags: node.js, youtube, google-authenticator

we upload a lot of videos to Youtube (from out AWS), it works great, but from time to time, (very seldom) we get this error:

```
140190904026944:error:0B07C065:x509 certificate routines:X509_STORE_add_cert:cert already in hash table:../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/x509/x509_lu.c:348 during [ytdapi.videos.insert]

at OAuth2Client._postRequest (google-auth-library/lib/auth/oauth2client.js:400:3)
at postRequestCb (google-auth-library/lib/auth/oauth2client.js:360:12)
at authCb (google-auth-library/lib/auth/oauth2client.js:366:7)
at google-auth-library/lib/auth/oauth2client.js:286:14
```

What does it mean and how to fix?